# CoffeeCup HTML editor doesn't seem to want to recognize "nav" when I try to create a rule.

Tags: html, css, nav

I've been trying to create a css rule within the html editor just to test if the selector "nav" works, but it doesn't. I tried my hardest but I've been stuck. For instance when I try to create a  styling rule for nav, it is not recognized by the html editor, non of the anchored elements under nav is recognized. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      nav {
        color: white;
        background-color: orange;
       }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1></h1>
        <h2></h2>
      </a)
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">FoodFolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
      <p>To enter frames.</p>
    </section>
      <footer>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="Pics/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="Pics/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
         <p>&copy; 2014 </p>
      </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anchor tag is not closed properly `</a)`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Which one are you referring to? I double checked all of them and they all seem to be closed correctly, and all them were generated automatically by the software.

Comment: The code you have pasted above has `<header><a href="index.html">  ....   </a)`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I don't know how I completely missed that. That was definitely the issue. Once again thanks for the help and for saving me a lot of time. :)